# no operator matches || these operands

Tags: c++

Hi im having trouble with an if statement in C++. When I compile my code I get an error stating " no operator "||" matches these operands". Any guesses? The project is a small text based game I'm creating in visual studio.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Prototypes
void introScreen(int);
string characterCreation(string);



int choice;
string characterName, wepon1, wepon2, bow, sword, mace;

const string sword = sword;
const string bow = bow;
const string mace = mace;

// Functions 

int main()
{
    introScreen(choice);

    return 0;
}


void introScreen(int choice)
{

    cout << "----------------------------------------\n"
        << "Welcome to the arena!\n"
        << "Select a menu option\n"
        << "-----------------------------------------\n"
        << "1. New Game\n"
        << "2. Load\n"
        << "3. Exit\n\n"
        << "Enter your desired number ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
        characterCreation(characterName);
    else
        if (choice == 2)
            exit(0);
        else
            if (choice == 3)
                exit(1);

}


string characterCreation(string characterName,string wepon1,string wepon2, const string bow, const string sword, const string mace)
{

    cout << "Welcome to the character creation menu!\n"
        << "Enter your name\n"
        << "Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, characterName);

    ofstream loadFile("Save.txt");
    loadFile << characterName << endl;

    cout << "\nEnter 2 wepons\n"
        << "Wepon list\n\n"
        << "Sword\n"
        << "Mace\n"
        << "Bow\n";
    cin >> wepon1, wepon2;

    if (wepon1 || wepon2 != bow || sword || mace)
    {
        cout << "\n\nThose wepons are invalid! Enter new ones\n";
        cout << "\nEnter 2 wepons\n"
            << "Wepon list\n\n"
            << "sword\n"
            << "mace\n"
            << "bow\n";
        cin >> wepon1, wepon2;
    }

    loadFile << wepon1 << endl
        << wepon2 << endl;


    return characerName;
}
```

Comment: Logical "or" doesn't work like this. You need to compare *each* weapon to *each* type.

Comment: @FredLarson I used to think people only made this mistake in Python, where logical `and` and `or` are spelled out as words. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: Oh, this won't work either: `cin >> wepon1, wepon2;`.

Comment: Isn't this the 3rd or 4th duplicate problem today?

Comment: @FredLarson good catch, I don't think that one would generate an error message - it would just silently do the wrong thing. Stupid comma operator.

Comment: @Mark Ransom With `-Wall` on gcc, a warning will be issued if the comma operator is used in a seemingly pointless scenario.

Comment: Why do people keep assuming that logical operators will expand to a Cartesian product of the surrounding operation?

Comment: This is a bit odd: `const string sword = sword;` [Recommend a bit of book-reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

The '||' operator is an evaluation of a logical condition and you are asking it to evaluate a string type.  Generally, when strings values are evaluated, they are evaluated as 
if (weapon1 != "") then...

Also, be careful about how you set the value.  String values are passed inside double quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realize that. Thanks for the help